# Storing mdb in database

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, personal-geodatabase

I am a beginner in database.

I have a script of integration Python/ArcPy which with each time or it is carried out, to create two databases (mdb):

1. integrable.mdb,
2. not integrable.mdb.

For the moment these databases are safeguarded in folders and with time I lose them.

I'm looking for a way to save feature classes and tables  each time they are created in a database that will be updated each time new data is created.
For the moment I don't see the way to do this.

Do you have an idea of how to do this?

The purpose of this approach is to save data and to have an archive so as not to lose data.

Comment: I think your solution will use Copy Features and Copy Rows but where are you planning to store the Feature Classes and Tables?  In other words are your databases spatially enabled as geodatabases?

Comment: yes the databases are activated as geodatabases we are using Oracle database system i think create an oracle database and put the mdb in it .

Comment: It’s the feature classes and tables that you put in it not the personal geodatabase that contains them. Please use the edit button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Access is both an application and a data format. Esri exploited this format to create "personal geodatabase" continers. But once you remove the data from the format, it is no longer an MDB, just rows and columns in Oracle tables within the Oracle database. Databases have a number of ways of managing data snapshots and ArcGIS has a number of ways to get data into database tables, but using an RDBMS as a way to permanently archive data is *really* inefficient. If you regularly lose data files in your filesystems, then losing tablespace files will be quite traumatic to your Oracle instance.